# Limit Definition for Half-Derivative

Tags: limits, derivatives, fractional-calculus

The derivative of a function $f$ is defined as
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Let
$$d_1(f,h)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
and, in fact, let all $d_n$ be defined by
$$\lim_{h\to 0} d_n(f,h)=f^{(n)}(x)$$
In order to obtain $d_2$, we can plug $d_1$ into itself to get
$$\frac{\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)}{h}-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}{h}$$
$$\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)-f(x+h)-f(x)}{h^2}$$
$$\frac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)-f(x)}{h^2}$$
and, in general, we can use induction to prove that, for natural $n$,
$$d_n(f,h)=\frac{1}{h^n}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}f(x+(n-k)h)$$
However, I am interested in finding $d_\frac{1}{2}$. It should satisfy
$$d_\frac{1}{2}(d_\frac{1}{2}(f,h),h)=d_1(f,h)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
So that when it is composed with itself as shown, $d_1$ is the result.

It can possibly be obtained by figuring out how to extend the expression
$$\frac{1}{h^n}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}f(x+(n-k)h)$$
to non-integer $n$. Does anybody have any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: You may want to check out fractional calculus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: @BobKrueger I know a little bit about it... I was just trying to find a *limit definition* of fractional derivatives.

Comment: Look up the Grunwald-Letnikov derivative.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Have you ever seen the Grunwald-Letnikov derivative for negative values?  You can make it rather interesting for the negative integers, as the result comes out to be the Riemann sum, if done correctly.  See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1):

One can extend this in a similar manner that the binomial expansion theorem is extended.  Note that $\binom nk=0$ if $k>n$ and $n$ is a natural number.  Thus, we have the [Grunwald-Letnikov derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCnwald%E2%80%93Letnikov_derivative),

> $$f^{(\alpha)}(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{h^\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom\alpha kf(x+(\alpha-k)h)\tag{$\alpha\ge0$}$$

An interesting point to note is that for $\alpha=-1$, we get

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=\lim_{h\to0}h\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(x-(1+k)h)$$

Or as you may better recognize it,

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^\infty f\left(x-\frac kn\right)$$

Which is extraodinarily similar to

$$\int_{x-1}^xf(t)~\mathrm dt=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(x-\frac kn\right)$$

Which I suppose would mean that a better all-enveloping fractional derivative could be given by

> $$f^{(\alpha)}(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{h^\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor1/|h|\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom\alpha kf(x+(\alpha-k)h)\tag{$\alpha\in\mathbb C$}$$

However, for non integer $\alpha$, this isn't well defined as $h\to0^-$, and so we assume we can replace this with the limit from the positive side:

> $$f^{(\alpha)}(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\alpha\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom\alpha kf\left(x+\frac{\alpha-k}n\right)\tag{$\alpha\in\mathbb C$}$$

Which now gives us sort of anti-derivatives as well.  Mainly,

$$\int_0^nf(x)~\mathrm dx=\sum_{k=1}^nf^{(-1)}(k)$$

---

Of course, one might note nothing unique about this particular extension.  One could include more parameters:

$$_\beta^+\mathbb D_x^\alpha f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\alpha\sum_{k=0}^{\beta n}(-1)^k\binom\alpha kf\left(x+\frac{\alpha-k}n\right)$$

And if we used $\frac d{dx}f(x)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}h$,

$$_\beta^-\mathbb D_x^\alpha f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\alpha\sum_{k=0}^{\beta n}(-1)^k\binom\alpha kf\left(x+\frac{k-\alpha}n\right)$$

Comment: (note that there is a slight problem here.  I'm a bit unsure with setting $h=1/n$, as the limit for $n\to\infty$ is not necessarily equal to the limit as $n\to-\infty$)