# Nth derivative of $y = f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I find how to deal with limits ([Nth Derivative of $y=f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385782/nth-derivative-of-y-fx)).

To deriviate without limits we have

$y'(x) = y'(f(x)) * f'(x) = \frac{\delta y}{\delta f} \frac{\delta f}{\delta x}$

$y''(x) = y''(f(x))f'(x)^2 + y'(f(x))f''(x)= \frac{\delta^2 y}{\delta^2 f}(\frac{\delta f}{\delta x})^2 + \frac{\delta y}{\delta x}\frac{\delta^2 f}{\delta^2 x}$

...

$y^{n} = ?$

I try to find a general form with maybe $\sum$'s and $\Pi$'s and maybe binomials.
Maybe the name is General form of nth chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I find Faà di Bruno's formula : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula